# import datetime but no attribute fromtimestamp OR timezone - Python

Tags: python, datetime

I cant understand why when I import datetime I am unable to access some methods eg

```
import datetime
datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'timezone' is not defined
```

Any ideas, could it be a pytz library conflict?

Thank you

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.11 @Connor

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import 'timezone' and 'datetime' properly:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
print(datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc))
```

And of course, make sure you don't name your file something like "timezone.py" or "datetime.py" ;)

UPDATE: This assumes you are running Python 3.2 or above

Comment: Hi, if I do I get >>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name timezone

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to call the module variables or classes using the `.` reference:

```
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

`datetime.timezone` means it's the `timezone` class inside `datetime`.

You usually import only the module, not all of the classes and methods included, because the module is being loaded as a module typed class to your globals stack.

If you want them all handy, like in your example, import using

```
from datetime import *
```

that will take each class from module and load it to your program globals, so you can use them.

Comment: This is all correct. It is with noting, though, that `from datetime import * ` will likely import functions and classes that you don't use.  Best practice is  to either only import the items you need or use the `import datetime` and the `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

I just want to point out that anyone having issues with datetime should consider the differences between python 2 and 3 (makes me sad) ; it caused me a lot of issues.

Hopefully that will help you debug quicker.